# PHP filter_input() not protecting from eval()

Tags: php, injection

I was updating some PHP code following the advice of not using `$_GET` and `$_POST` anymore but instead to switch to the safer `filter_input()` functions.

I was thinking that function would save me in this stupid case:

```
<?php 

eval($_GET["var"]);

?>
```

which when called as `localhost/test.php?var=phpinfo();` spits the whole PHP info page. So I changed it to:

```
<?php 

eval(filter_input(INPUT_GET, "var", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));

?>
```

However it seems that the above is still vulnerable to the same attack.
Which should be the correct way of securing the `eval()` in the case above?

Comment: The current case doesn't make much sense: it's contradictory. Eval is used to evaluate code and yet you want it not be evaluated. If you could provide the real/whole case we might be able to give you a workaround or a suitable solution.

Comment: It doesn't make sense hardening eval against code execution. This is because the purpose of eval is code execution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`filter_input` is designed to filter out things that may cause issues with HTML output: from the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) "Strip tags, optionally strip or encode special characters."

`phpinfo()` doesn't include any special characters, or tags, so is passed through exactly as provided, then `eval` executes it. In fact, this is the case for a lot of PHP code - you're using a filter designed for a different purpose.

As @SteffanUllrich says, you can't secure `eval` - it executes PHP, which is almost exactly what you want to prevent. Your best option at this point is to rewrite your code to avoid using the `eval` function.

Ways to do this could include passing an indirect reference to a function (e.g. if you get a parameter of `1`, use a `switch` block to execute `function_one()`), or just hardcoding each PHP file to do a specific thing. If you provide any way for an end user to provide PHP code which is executed, you're likely to have problems.

Answer (score 7):

> Which should be the correct way of securing the eval() in the case above?

There is no way to secure input to eval. Just don't use eval on any user-generated data.

Comment: so the only case of code injection possible with filter_input() is when it is coupled with the eval() function? I won't ever use eval() however it was the most stupid test I came up to check the filter_input() function and it miserably failed :(

Comment: @sarah.ferguson: That's not what I said. For instance it would also be unsafe to write user input (even filtered) into a file and then include this file as PHP code. And there are probably more ways.

Comment: No. Code injection can also occur via preg_replace(), create_function(), include/require (and probably others). filter_input() is not a magic fix - far from it.